# Changing position of a character in a string

Tags: sed

String:

```
34    /foo/bar_11,,,
```

I want to insert "34" instead of the second comma. So my string should look like this:

```
/foo/bar_11,34,
```

How I can do it?

Comment: So you want to *move* the `34` from the start of the line?

Comment: @steeldriver, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is using *capture groups* to capture the thing you want to move, and the thing you want to move it past, optionally matching and discarding any unwanted characters such as whitespace, and then replace them in the desired order

Ex.

```
$ sed -E 's/^([[:alnum:]]+)[[:blank:]]*([^,]*,[^,]*),/\2\1/' <<< '34    /foo/bar_11,,,'
/foo/bar_11,34,
```